# A* pathfinding game system exit issue

Tags: java, a-star

I am making a game where a badGuy AI is trying to chase me while I use arrow keys to move away. In my main I have a try catch block for if the player attempts to exit the screen border. For some reason however when I click on start I get the exception which I have a system print out saying "GAME OVER, you exited the map". Without my reCalcPath method in the badguy class this does not happen so it must be an issue within this method.

For this method I have a map array. This array is a 40x40 boolean array of 20x20 pixels/cells/squares which states true if I have clicked on that cell position if previously false, painting a white square and visa versa. Now I thought, check the cell position of the badGuy, then check all of his neighbouring cells, if the state of that cell is false i.e. no cell is painted (which means there is no wall blocking him in this sense), then check for the distance between him and my player. I use a Euclidean distance approach by treating xPlayer-xbadGuy, yPLayer-xBadGuy as the opposite and adjacent sides of a triangle. Using pythagoras I get the hypotenuse. Do this for each neighbouring cell, the one with the smallest hypotenuse means shortest distance. Now this is not working at all as when its called the game crashes. Ignore the move method as that is irrelevant if recalcpath won't work

***Main***

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

public class AStarMaze extends JFrame implements Runnable, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, KeyListener {

    // member data
    private boolean isInitialised = false;
    private BufferStrategy strategy;
    private Graphics offscreenBuffer;
    public boolean map[][] = new boolean[40][40];
    private boolean isGameRunning = false;
    private BadGuy badguy;
    private Player player;
    private int startI, startJ;
    private int endI, endJ;

    private String pFilePath, bgFilePath;

    // constructor
    public AStarMaze () {

        //Display the window, centred on the screen
        Dimension screensize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = screensize.width/2 - 400;
        int y = screensize.height/2 - 400;
        setBounds(x, y, 800, 800);
        setVisible(true);
        this.setTitle("A* Pathfinding Demo");

        bgFilePath = "C:\\Users\\brads\\IdeaProjects\\PathfindingAssignment\\src\\badguy.png";
        pFilePath = "C:\\Users\\brads\\IdeaProjects\\PathfindingAssignment\\src\\player.png";
        // load raster graphics and instantiate game objects
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(bgFilePath);
        Image img = icon.getImage();
        badguy = new BadGuy(img);
        icon = new ImageIcon(pFilePath);
        img = icon.getImage();
        player = new Player(img);

        // create and start our animation thread
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

        // initialise double-buffering
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        strategy = getBufferStrategy();
        offscreenBuffer = strategy.getDrawGraphics();

        // register the Jframe itself to receive mouse and keyboard events
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);

        // initialise the map state
        for (x=0;x<40;x++) {
            for (y=0;y<40;y++) {
                map[x][y]=false;
            }
        }

        isInitialised = true;
    }

    public boolean[][] getMap(){
        return map;
    }

    // thread's entry point
    public void run() {
        long loops=0;
        while ( 1==1 ) {
            // 1: sleep for 1/5 sec
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        try {
            // 2: animate game objects
            if (isGameRunning) {
                loops++;
                player.move(map); // player moves every frame
                if (loops % 3 == 0) // badguy moves once every 3 frames
                    badguy.reCalcPath(map,player.x,player.y);
                  //  badguy.move(map, player.x, player.y);
            }

            // 3: force an application repaint
            this.repaint();
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){

            System.out.println("GAME OVER, you exited the map");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        }
    }

    private void loadMaze() {
        String filename = "C:\\Users\\brads\\IdeaProjects\\PathfindingAssignment\\maze.txt";
        String textinput = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            textinput = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) { }

        if (textinput!=null) {
            for (int x=0;x<40;x++) {
                for (int y=0;y<40;y++) {
                    map[x][y] = (textinput.charAt(x*40+y)=='1');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveMaze() {
        // pack maze into a string
        String outputtext="";
        for (int x=0;x<40;x++) {
            for (int y=0;y<40;y++) {
                if (map[x][y])
                    outputtext+="1";
                else
                    outputtext+="0";
            }
        }

        try {
            String filename = "C:\\Users\\brads\\IdeaProjects\\PathfindingAssignment\\maze.txt";
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
            writer.write(outputtext);
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    // mouse events which must be implemented for MouseListener
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!isGameRunning) {
            // was the click on the 'start button'?
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();
            if (x>=15 && x<=85 && y>=40 && y<=70) {
                isGameRunning=true;
                return;
            }
            // or the 'load' button?
            if (x>=315 && x<=385 && y>=40 && y<=70) {
                loadMaze();
                return;
            }
            // or the 'save' button?
            if (x>=415 && x<=485 && y>=40 && y<=70) {
                saveMaze();
                return;
            }
        }

        // determine which cell of the gameState array was clicked on
        int x = e.getX()/20;
        int y = e.getY()/20;
        // toggle the state of the cell
        map[x][y] = !map[x][y];
        // throw an extra repaint, to get immediate visual feedback
        this.repaint();
        // store mouse position so that each tiny drag doesn't toggle the cell
        // (see mouseDragged method below)
        prevx=x;
        prevy=y;
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    //

    // mouse events which must be implemented for MouseMotionListener
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}

    // mouse position on previous mouseDragged event
    // must be member variables for lifetime reasons
    int prevx=-1, prevy=-1;
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // determine which cell of the gameState array was clicked on
        // and make sure it has changed since the last mouseDragged event
        int x = e.getX()/20;
        int y = e.getY()/20;
        if (x!=prevx || y!=prevy) {
            // toggle the state of the cell
            map[x][y] = !map[x][y];
            // throw an extra repaint, to get immediate visual feedback
            this.repaint();
            // store mouse position so that each tiny drag doesn't toggle the cell
            prevx=x;
            prevy=y;
        }
    }
    //

    // Keyboard events
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            player.setXSpeed(-1);
        else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            player.setXSpeed(1);
        else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            player.setYSpeed(-1);
        else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            player.setYSpeed(1);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            player.setXSpeed(0);
        else if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            player.setYSpeed(0);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }
    //

    // application's paint method
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (!isInitialised)
            return;

        g = offscreenBuffer; // draw to offscreen buffer

        // clear the canvas with a big black rectangle
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);

        // redraw the map
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        for (int x=0;x<40;x++) {
            for (int y=0;y<40;y++) {
                if (map[x][y]) {
                    g.fillRect(x*20, y*20, 20, 20);
                }
            }
        }
        // redraw the player and badguy
        // paint the game objects
        player.paint(g);
        badguy.paint(g);

        if (!isGameRunning) {
            // game is not running..
            // draw a 'start button' as a rectangle with text on top
            // also draw 'load' and 'save' buttons
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(15, 40, 70, 30);
            g.fillRect(315, 40, 70, 30);
            g.fillRect(415, 40, 70, 30);
            g.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString("Start", 22, 62);
            g.drawString("Load", 322, 62);
            g.drawString("Save", 422, 62);
        }

        // flip the buffers
        strategy.show();
    }

    // application entry point
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AStarMaze w = new AStarMaze();
    }

}
```

***Player Class***

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;


public class Player {

    Image myImage;
    int x=0,y=0;
    int xSpeed=0, ySpeed=0;

    public Player( Image i ) {
        myImage=i;
        x=10;
        y=35;
    }

    public void setXSpeed( int x ) {
        xSpeed=x;
    }

    public void setYSpeed( int y ) {
        ySpeed=y;
    }

    public void move(boolean map[][]) {
        int newx=x+xSpeed;
        int newy=y+ySpeed;
        if (!map[newx][newy]) {
            x=newx;
            y=newy;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(myImage, x*20, y*20, null);
    }

}
```

***Bad Guy***

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

public class BadGuy {

    Image myImage;
    int x=0,y=0;
    int distanceX = 0, distanceY = 0;
    boolean hasPath=false;

    public BadGuy( Image i ) {
        myImage=i;
        x = 30;
        y = 10;
    }

    public void reCalcPath(boolean map[][],int targx, int targy) {
//         TO DO: calculate A* path to targx,targy, taking account of walls defined in map[][]
        int totalDistance = 0;
        for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                if (!map[(x / 20) + i][(y / 20) + j]) {
                    if ((((targx - x) ^ 2) + ((targy - y) ^ 2)) <= totalDistance) {

                        totalDistance = (((targx - x) ^ 2) + ((targy - y) ^ 2));
                        x = ((x / 20) + i);
                        y = ((y / 20) + j);
                        return;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
            System.out.println("Not working");
    }


//    public void move(boolean map[][],int targx, int targy) {
//        if (hasPath) {
//            // TO DO: follow A* path, if we have one defined
//        }
//        else if(map[x / 20][y / 20]) {
//            hasPath = false;
//        }
//    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(myImage, x*20, y*20, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: `^` is bitwise xor not exponent. Use `Math.pow(x, 2)` or `x*x` to square numbers.

Comment: This is a lot of code to review. It would help if you could strip out anything not directly related to the problem and create a [mre].

Comment: Classic AWT/Swing mistake: embedding all the code inside the UI so it can't be tested independently.  You should think about decomposing this monster into smaller classes that you can JUnit test independently.  Inject instances into the UI and let it use what it needs once the code is tested and shaken out.

Comment: Corollary to duffymo's comment: when you do find a bug, the first step is to write a test that will expose it, so that the bug is apparent in the test harness.  Then proceed to fix the bug.  Exposing the bug in a test in this case will lead to the need to write smaller modular code that can be tested.

Comment: Another problem is the error message itself: `catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)` you catch the exception but then just print a lame error message.  Printing the stack trace would help locate where the bug actually is.  In general it's better to allow exceptions to propagate up the stack and not catch them at all.  The right thing happens by default.

Comment: Looks like getting rid of that stupid try and catch block did it. The error is in reCalcPath method in badGuy class where map[ x / 20 + i ][ j / 20 + j] can give an array index out of bounds as i can be negative 1 as well as j and if x or y = 0 and i or j is -1 then that makes map[-1][j] or map[-1][-1] or map[i][-1] which is out of the bounds. The math.pow was also another issue which I fixed and apologies for throwing all of my code at all of you, I just wasn't sure where the error was occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your catch block is triggered by an IndexOutOfBoundsException.  One easy way to find more information about your error is to log or output the stack trace.  You can do that in your code by adding `e.printStackTrace()` to your catch block:

```
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            System.out.println("GAME OVER, you exited the map");
            e.printStackTrace()
            System.exit(-1);
        }
```

This should show you the line number that's causing your problem.

Looking at the code in your reCalcPath method, my educated guess is the line causing the problem is this: `if (!map[(x / 20) + i][(y / 20) + j]) {`.  If either `(x / 20) + i` or `(y / 20) + j` are less than 0 or greater than your map dimensions, it will throw the IndexOutOfBoundsException that you are seeing.  In the case where you start and x=30, y=10, i=-1, and j=-1, that evaluates to map[0][-1].

This is what's known as an edge case.  You need to check for the case where your x and y are on the edges of the grid.  In that situation the neighboring grid cells are outside of the map and will throw an exception.